# Excel - how to match a column header with a row header (dates) and return a lookup value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've looked high and low for this and can't find a solution. Plenty with formulas, but it must be in VBA.

I have a range of text in column A (A2:A100) and dates in column B (B2:B100), with sequential calendar dates in row 1 (C1:Z1). For every cell in the matrix/table, if the date in column B is the same as the date in row 1, the text in corresponding column A must be displayed. I can't use a VLOOKUP or MATCH formula, as the columns are narrow and don't display the full text unwrapped because of the formula in the adjacent cell. Thanks for any guidance. In the below, N2 must be "Electrician chasing", since N1 is the same as B2.

[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add screenshot? • Also please clarify *"I have a range of text in column A … and dates in column B"* vs *"if the date in column A is …"* vs *"the text in corresponding column B"* is it text or dates? This is completely confusing. Screenshot would clarify everything.

Comment: If you want text to flow over empty cells, they'll have to be truly empty, so formulas won't help here - you'll need to do it programatically as @harassed-dad suggests.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this (and you got your columns A and B the wrong way round)

```
 Sub LoopAndDisplay
 Dim r as range
 For each r in range("C2:Z200")
     If cells(1,r.column) = cells(r.row,2) then 'if date above matches column B then 
        r = cells(r.row,1)  'display contents of column A
     End If
 Next R
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Harrassed Dad, but my document freezes when I try your code. Looks like it goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't view images so I've had to guess on your layout - but it works here. Try stepping through the code using f8 and checking the values of the cells statements by hovering your mouse over them.